# How to disable dynamic contrast in Kubuntu?

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, brightness

My environment is kubuntu 14.04 and graphic card is nvidia GTX 560. The problem is with dynamic contrast changes. For example when I open "bright" webpages it looks like monitor is brightening up as well, when I go to "dark" pages, screen dims.

It doesn't look like it happens because some monitor setting - I use same screen with Windows os and the problem does not appear.

How do I disable this feature?

Comment: do you have dual boot with windows?

Comment: Yes, I do have dual boot.

Comment: did you have this issue in windows? and windows 8 or other version do you have ?

Comment: As it says in question - I do not experience such problem with Windows.

Comment: OK. please see this tread to ensure http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-desktop/how-do-i-disable-auto-brightness/e50fdfe0-d0e4-471c-8c33-92e79d3366e3

Comment: You need to provide a bit more information about your system. What driver are you using for you nvidia card? the default nouveau driver or the proprietary one?

Comment: Nvidia X Server Settings says I am using NVIDIA Driver Version 340.32 for Linux-x86_64.

Comment: I believe this is an option built into some desktop monitors (in the form of Dynamic Contrast I believe). are you using MacBook screen?

Comment: Are you on a laptop or desktop?